# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax:help needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I want to create mysql database and tables on phpmyadmin.

The code is as follows:

```
create database android_api /** Creating Database **/

use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

But encountered an error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Â  use android_api /** Selecting Database **/ Â  create table
>   `users`( Â Â ' at line 2

What is the problem here, any help.

Comment: get rid of comments from the sql statements and separate them with `;`

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because of the `comments`. Try with -

```
create database android_api;
use android_api;
create table users(
   uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);
```

If you want the commensts -

```
create database android_api; # Creating Database
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't caused by the comment in the `sql statement`, it is caused by the blank line with something else(HEX code: `20 20 20 20 c2 a0`), but I dont know how it occurs. May be this is a bug in some where. The best way is remove the blank line and add `;` to each statement, this will fix the problem. Try it.

```
create database android_api; /** Creating Database **/
use android_api; /** Selecting Database **/
create table users(
   uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```